# Hyperlink redirect is not working in Django

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

I have the below code as part of my project. But instead of redirecting to the HTML page (`contact.html`), it is redirecting back to the home page or `index.html`.

`main_app/urls.py`:

```
path("", home_views.index, name='home_page'),
path("contact", home_views.contact, name='contact'),
```

`main_app/home_views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Varsity/index.html')
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'Varsity/contact.html')
```

`Varsity/index.html`:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
```

Terminal

```
[05/Sep/2022 14:34:43] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Comment: Python by itself does nothing with this code, we need to know which framework and libraries you are using etc.

Comment: Django framework

Comment: There is some kind of redirect, it should give `200` because that Hyperlink SHOULD NOT redirect, it's standard link by href.